# Let $A$ be a finite set. Prove that there exists an $f:n \to A$ that is onto $A$ for some $n \in \omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set.  Prove that there exists an $f:n \to A$ that is onto $A$ for some $n \in \omega$.

Here by finite we mean: A set $X$ is finite iff there is a one-to-one function $f:X→n$ for some natural number $n$.

I can see that $A$ being finite implies the existence of some one-to-one function $g:A\to N$ for some $N\in \omega$. and thus, its inverse function will be $g^{-1}:N\to A$, with $g$ onto as needed.  But is it this simple?  Is it always the case that such an inverse exists, or do we need to prove by induction on $n$?

Comment: When you say "$n$" I think you mean "$\{1, 2, ...., n\}$."  It may also help to define "$\omega$" and "natural number" (does it include 0? Is the empty set finite?)

Comment: @Michael it's rather $\{0,1, \dots, n-1\}$.

Comment: @Berci :?? Is it the case Berci = George W Kush?

Comment: With this definition, yes, it's that simple..

Comment: In set theory, natural numbers are inductively encoded as $n=\{0,1, \dots, n-1\}$, starting with $0:=\emptyset,\ 1:=\{\emptyset\}$, and so on.